# Writing for iOS and Android - possible for this function?

Tags: android, ios

Read a number of questions on writing in just one language for both iOS and Android and what I learned is that it depends on the special functions you need. What I want to build is a very simple app that will ask the user what he or she is doing. We need this for billing the customers but my co-workers keep forgetting to update their time-sheet, so I want to write this little app that pops-up every x minutes and asks them what their doing. At the end of the day the list will be sent by e-mail or whatever.

Anyway.... is a pop-up from an app from the background a 'special' function? Can a general language be used on both for this?

Edit: I have searched for crossplatform tools, but all replies talk about specific functions that still require native coding. That is why I was wondering if something as simple as a popup with question and entering / saving a text, would be native or could easily be handled with a crossplatform tool.

Comment: There's a bunch of different tools available.  Try searching for iOS Android cross platform tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure what you describe can be achieved with using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). Its a free solution and it comes with a lot of good documentation to get you up and running quickly. You'll need to use AngularJS for developing apps with Ionic so that might be a good solution if you know your way around that framework, or if you are familiar with Javascript or have done some web development before.

On regards to your question regarding native functionality (by popups I assume you mean notifications) Ionic sits on top of Cordova so there is a huge amount of native plugins that you can use to implement native functionality. You can take a look at plugins [here](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Xamarin` to create a cross platform applications. I am satisfied with `Xamarin` platform at the moment. I have been working on native iOS, java for Android also.

Please keep in your mind that, it would be great if you are familar with these platforms because `Xamarin` is just a wrapper of methods which exist in the native platforms. Since I am familar with native Android and iOS, it makes me comfortable when I work on `Xamarin` platform.

My personal recommendation is to stick with Native platform. But if you have to work on cross platform, I believe `Xamarin` is a good option.

**Pros:**

If you are familiar with C#, it will help you a lot to develop an application for android, ios and windows platforms in `Xamarin`.

It is demanding platforms, and many big companies are looking Xamarin developers especially after the Microsoft acquisition.

**Cons:**

You need to buy a license.

---

There are other platforms as well, but I did not use any of them. Here are some of them

- Cordova
- HTML5
- Unity
- PhoneGap
- Appcelerator
- Corona
- Qt

You may find useful the following urls

- http://appindex.com/blog/ten-best-cross-platform-development-mobile-enterprises/
- http://www.developereconomics.com/pros-cons-top-5-cross-platform-tools/